# Image string to Fat-free Framework via AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to upload an image as a string, which I get from using Croppie.js, to a server running the Fat-Free Framework.  I have verified that the data is there before the `$.ajax()` call but my PHP can't display it.  Other data, such as email, show up just fine if I comment out processing the posted image data.  Here is my Javascript:

```
$picturePreview.croppie('result').then(function (imageData) {
  // imageData is processed below to pop off the beginning of
  // the Base64 string including the filetype and base information

  var postData = {
      email         : $('#email').val(),
      picture       : imageData.substr(imageData.indexOf(',') + 1)
    };

  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'user',
    data: postData,
    beforeSend: function() {
      // This returns all data, including the image string:
      console.log(postData);
    }
  });
});
```

And here is my `post` function for my user class, which is mapped correctly:

```
function post($f3) {
  global $handler; // This is a global variable for PhpConsole

  $email =          $f3->get('POST.email');
  $picture =        $f3->get('POST.picture');
  // I've tried limiting the above to 4 characters and it still won't work

  $handler->debug($email, "heres the email"); // This outputs fine if the next line is commented out
  $handler->debug($picture, "heres the pic");
}
```

I've also tried to increase the `php_value` for `post_max_size` to up to `100M` and still nothing.  Why does a Base64 string containing image data break my app?  Should I be doing it another way?

Comment: "email, show up just fine if I comment out processing the posted image data" >> which line exactly do you comment out? Also make sure your debugger can handle large strings.

Comment: are you sure the image data is base64 encoded?

Comment: @xfra35 I actually have to comment out both lines having to do with `$picture`; the variable assignment and the `$handler` line.  @ikkez when I output the raw Javascript variable `postData.picture` it contains both the image encoding and `base64`, so I am pretty sure that it is encoded that way.

Comment: I used F3 with any jquery image plugins works without any problem :)

Comment: Did you mean croppic.js? if yes then its working flawless :p